# Why are some iPhone 13 Pro photos extremely resampled?

Tags: iphone, camera

I have an iPhone 13 Pro and I take thousands of photos with it. Most of them are just fine, but I have a couple that are resampled beyond usability that I cannot understand.

For example the attached photo is one of a series of four photos all shot of the same subject. It is the same dimensions as the others and I didn't change any settings, but it is clearly resampled horribly.

What is the cause and how can I prevent it from happening in the future?

[image]

For comparison, here is one that was processed normally.

[image]

Blow-up screenshot of first image, to make it easier to see on a smaller device…

[image]

Comment: At a guess it's tried to do a multi exposure HDR, due to the large difference in light levels under the canopy compared to the background. We'd need to see one it didn't process to compare.

Comment: added another image for comparison.

Comment: Oh, at first I was only looking at this on my phone. Now I've seen it on the compy with better zoom… that is truly weird. I honestly have no idea how it's done that to it. I've added a blown-up section of the first pic to make it easier to see on a smaller screen. It really looks like some 'painting' interpretation plugin, not an attempt to simply 'improve' the image.